# How to return just one value in Powershell command?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell command (which checks % CPU usage of a process) that returns me 2 values (Instance name + CPU%). I want to return just ONE value (CPU%). What should I add to this script to do that?
Example below:

```
$Processname = "slack"
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process($Processname)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples
$Samples | Select `
InstanceName,
@{Name=”CPU %”;Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}
```

The return value is:

```
InstanceName CPU %
------------ -----
slack            0
```

I want only the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
$Processname = "slack"
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process($Processname)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples
($Samples | Select InstanceName, @{Name=”CPU”;Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}).CPU
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first expand the `CookedValue` property (using [`ExpandProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters), the general way *to just return one value from a PowerShell object*) and then make the calculation:

```
[Decimal]::Round((($Samples | Select -Expand CookedValue) / $CpuCores), 2)
```